# Google Cloud Datastore Entity Property saved as blob instead os string

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I am inserting entities into a Google Cloud Datastore, but the string are stored as blobs / base64 strings:

```
complete_key = client.key('Task', 'sample_task')

task = datastore.Entity(key=complete_key)

task.update({
    'category': 'Personal',
    'done': False,
    'priority': 4,
    'description': 'Learn Cloud Datastore'
})

client.put(task)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Python2 strings are actually bytes: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2791. So I upgraded to Python3 and now strings are saved as strings in the datastore.

Comment: You can also add a 'u' in front of strings in Py2 to make them UTF-8 strings. For example, u'Learn Cloud Datastore'